# Log4j2 log hibernate parameters binding

Tags: hibernate, binding, parameters, log4j2

Does anyone have an example of how to log hibernate sql parameters with log4j2? I know how to log them with log4j 1.x, but I couldn't do this with 2.0 beta 3 version (last version so far) of log4j.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I've seen other responses to this question, but none that log **just the sql substitution parameters**. If you set the `org.hibernate.type` Logger category, you will get a TON of output!

All I want to see is the substituted values. If that's what you want as well, read on...

In summary the Logger category you want to configure is called:

```
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder
```

And you need to set its value to `TRACE`

That said, below are `.properties` style and XML configurations that make this work.

`.properties` style:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, Console
log4j.appender.Console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.Console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n
# Below is the line to dump ONLY the bind variables
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
  <appender name="Console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender"> 
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/> 
    </layout> 
  </appender> 

  <root> 
    <priority value="DEBUG" /> 
    <appender-ref ref="Console" /> 
  </root>

  <logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder">
    <level value="TRACE" />
    <appender-ref ref="Console" />
  </logger>

</log4j:configuration>
```

The output will look like:

```
10:58:47,631 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] (Thread-5212 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-475186579)) binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - 165
10:58:47,631 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] (Thread-5212 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-475186579)) binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - 1390496100822
```

Have fun!